# I accidentally removed my ecryptfs-utils package. Now I cannot log in. Any chance to regain access to the home directory?

Tags: mount, filesystem, encryption, ecryptfs

I accidentally removed my ecryptfs-utils package using sudo remove ecryptfs-utils. Is there any way I could regain access to the home directory?

When I try to log in now I just get looped back to the login screen. I can open a tty terminal and all it says in the home directory is: Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop and README.txt

The README.txt file says:

> "THIS DIRECTORY HAS BEEN UNMOUNTED TO PROTECT YOUR DATA
>
> From the graphical desktop, click on:
>
> "Access Your Private Data"
>
> or
>
> From the command line, run:
>
> ecryptfs-mount-private

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10.

Update: I tried to copy the ecryptfs files from /usr/share and /usr/bin on another machine and that didn't work. (I think I got some password incorrect errors). However, that machine was running Raspbian. I wasn't able to install from tty by downloading ecryptfs-utils for some reason, got some IP's not found errors, although the Internet connection seems to work otherwise.

Comment: After logging in from tty1, try installing the encrpyt utils package and then rebooting to make the mounting scripts run as before. If not possible, grab a binary of the package and use a live usb or any way to put the binary versions of those utilities into your /usr/bin directory.

Comment: Well I tried to copy the ecryptfs files from /usr/share and /usr/bin on another machine and that didn't work. However, that machine was running Raspbian. I wasn't able to install from tty by downloading for some reason, got some IP's not found errors, although the Internet connection seems to work otherwise.

Comment: I think the encrypted files need the original ecryptfs version, no? Correct or incorrect? I cannot just replace the ecryptfs-utils files with a new installation, can I?

Comment: Get a live system with version matching your installed system and boot it from some removable media. Chroot from there into your installed system. Reinstall the missing packages. I used to shoot myself in the foot so often before on Gentoo and Ubuntu as well, I had to do this at least half a dozen times myself as well.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this after many many attempts over several months with rest in between. From login screen I went to TTY1 and logged in as sudoer. Then I could not install ecryptfs-utils for a long time which turned out to be caused probably by Ubuntu not supporting Wily anymore. So I went to /etc/apt/sources.list and changed all instances of the word wily to xenial and after that I could reinstall ecryptfs-utils. Maybe it's one of those things that shouldn't work but actually did.